# Power series corresponding to $[a]\in \operatorname{End}(E)$ ($a \in R_K$) can be expressed as $[a](t)=at+\text{(term higher than degree $2$)}$?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, power-series, formal-groups

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve which has complex multiplication on $K$.
Let $R_K$ be ring of integers of $K$.
Let  $ \hat{E}$ be its formal group of $E$.

Take $a \in{R_K}$ and $[a] \in \operatorname{End}E$ . Then there is unique corresponding homomorphism of formal group, $[a](t) \in \operatorname{End}\hat{E}$.

My question is, how can I prove $[a](t)=at+\text{(term higher than degree $2$)}$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\omega_E$ be an invaraint differential on $E$. Then $[a]$ satisfies $[a]^*\omega_E=a\omega_E$. That's over $K$, so the same formula holds on the formal group, i.e., $\widehat{[a]}\omega_{\hat E}=a\omega_{\hat E}$. On the other hand, if you write $\widehat{[a]}(T)=cT+\text{h.o.t.}$, then $\widehat{[a]}\omega_{\hat E}=c\omega_{\hat E}$. Hence $c=a$.

Comment: I never expected to receive an answer from the author of that great book. 
Could you tell me what the definition of $ \hat[a]$ is?My understanding is that, if we write $[a]((x,y))=(φ_1(t)),φ2(t))$, then $ \hat{[a]}(t)＝-φ_1(t)/φ_2(t)$.But  I’m having trouble to understand what $ \hat[a](ω_\hat E)$ is.This is embarrassing, but I may also misunderstand the definition of $ \hat{[a]}(t)$.

Comment: Any endomorphism $\phi:E\to E$ induces an endomorphism $\hat\phi:\hat E\to\hat E$ of the formal group. Explicitly, if $\phi(x,y)=\bigl(f(x,y),g(x,y)\bigr)$ for rational functions $f$ and $g$, then $\hat\phi(T) = -\dfrac{f(x(T),y(T))}{g(x(T),y(T))}$, where the expressions for $x(T)$ and $y(T)$ in terms of the formal group parameter $T$ can be found, for example, in my elliptic curves book.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to your help, I could understand the definition of   $\widehat{[a]}(T)$ but I'm stuck with understanding the definition of $\widehat{[a]}\omega_{\hat E}$. Could you tell me what the $\widehat{[a]}\omega_{\hat E}$ is ?

Comment: It should really be the pullback, $\widetilde{[a]}^*\omega_{\hat E}$, which by definition is
$$\omega_{\hat E}\bigl(\widetilde{[a]}(T)\bigr).$$
Since you know the power series for $\widetilde{[a]}(T)$, you can just substitute it into the power series for $\omega_{\hat E}(T)$. Thus if $\omega_{\hat E}(T)=G(T)\,dT$ , then
$$\widetilde{[a]}^*\omega_{\hat E} = \omega_{\hat E}\bigl(\widetilde{[a]}(T)\bigr)
= G\bigl(\widetilde{[a]}(T)\bigr)\, d\bigl(\widetilde{[a]}(T)]\bigr)
= G\bigl(\widetilde{[a]}(T)\bigr)\cdot\widetilde{[a]}'(T)\,dT.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, The last thing I don't still understand is why $[a]^*\omega_E=a\omega_E$ implies it's formal group version, $\widehat{[a]}^* \omega_{\hat E}=a\omega_{\hat E}$. Could you tell me why does this hold ? (Maybe I need to know some relation between $ω_E$ and $ω_ \hat{E}$ )